# Why was javascript Observable not called EventStream instead?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

Observables seem to be merely "event streams". The author of https://egghead.io/lessons/rxjs-introducing-the-observable seem to slip into calling them streams (even though he tries to consequently call them 'asynchronous collections', or 'collections that arrive over time', which seems contrived).

Streams are intuitively something which is laid out over time, imho.

The author of (The introduction to Reactive Programming you've been missing) https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754 goes all the way, and just calls them "event streams".

So, why were they called Observables and not just EventStreams?

Comment: Was it merely to avoid a naming conflict / confusion since this library already existed? https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream

Comment: Because an array `[1,2,3,4,5]` , `99`  are not a stream nor an event.And still you can Observe on it.

Comment: @RoyiNamir is an array an Observable?

Comment: I meant `Observable.of([..])` , where it doesn't contain any events . (_Observe on it._). You suggest That `EventStream.of([..])` , but does one element in the array is considered as an event ?

Comment: Also from official docs : Observable : _A representation of any set of **values** over any amount of **time**. This is the most basic building block of RxJS._. So we're not talking about events here

Comment: So you can basically create an eventstream from an array? That makes intuitive sense to me, atleast. You react to the values in the array as if they were events happening at a certain time, one after the other. Maybe the confusion lies in that they are not Event-objects per se, but I'm talking about events as in common language: something which happens/arrives at some specific time.

Comment: What i'm trying to tell you that `DataStream` would be more appropriate than `EventStream`. Since we're talking about data AND events ( `Observable.fromEvent` - for example)

Comment: But year, it bascically answers my question: Because EventStream may imply that it is a Steam of Event objects. According to existing naming conventions. I see why they would want to avoid that. Thanks.

Comment: Ok yeah. DataStream would work for me! :) Atleast it implies that it is a steam, which is a useful and intuitive concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name `Observable` comes from the ["Observer pattern"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), which partly inspired reactive programming. Jafar Husain gives a great explanation in [this interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwP1TNXE6fc).

I think `EventStream` is simply too broad. An `Observable` is sort of like a sub-type of an event stream. You can also have `Subject`, `BehaviorSubject`, and all other kinds of things that encapsulate the concept of a stream.

`Observable` is a good name because the only thing you can do with one is "observe" it. You can `.subscribe` and act on the values that come through, but you can't "add events" to it. `EventStream` doesn't imply that from the name. `EventStream.addEvent('click')` seems like a perfectly reasonable method.

At the end of the day, it really is just an opinion, though :)

Answer (score 0):

I disagree that EventStream is too broad. It is too specific.

Observers observe something. A clock is an observable. It can be modeled as a single changing value. Note 'value'.

Observables are named after the observer design pattern.

Modeling observables, such as a clock, as a stream of events forces an ontology onto the user that may not be compatible with their conceptual lexicon.

Remaining with Observable as the subject of any observation keeps things at the highest level of abstraction and usefulness.

Comment: I'd be fine with DataStream as well. It implies in its very name that it is something that arrives over time, whereas Observable doesn't necessarily.